# Remove GET parameter in URL before calling a page (before launching the route) in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, routes, coldfusion-11

I have problem with my application (main page: http://hostname/myapplication/). 
I'm trying (with angularJs 1) to implement the routes.

The page contents different links like:

- http://hostname/myapplication/index.cfm#/all-contacts
- http://hostname/myapplication/index.cfm#/add-contacts
- http://hostname/myapplication/index.cfm#/view-contacts/10890

**My problem:** a parameter "ticket" (due to an authentication system) is inserted in the url of the page when the page is called:

http://hostname/myapplication/index.cfm?ticket=12345#/add-contacts

The ticket is not inserted at the end (I don't know the reason) and the page is called but the data are not correctly displayed. I have some AJAX queries defined in the controlers and factories.

The url generated for doing AJAX appers in the console with this error:

```
GET http://hostname/myapplication/countries.cfc?method=getCountries&countryid=undefined

--> 302 Document Moved

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://loginsystem/login?loginRequestId=blabla. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

I think that when the page or an AJAX query is loaded the authentication system tries each time to reload.

Do you have an idea for solving this issue? Is it a problem of Angular, Server or authentication system?

Is it possible before calling a page to clean the url (delete the parameter "ticket") for allowing to the route to be working ? I would like to test this kind of solution for solving the problem.

Could you please help me for solving this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I create the application (module, controler factory) and all is working without the authentication system. I can add the files if you need. The problem appears after that the login is ok. The ticket is inserted in the url.

Comment: I am just telling that you should add the code too in your question. So that people can answer easily.

Comment: what does "page is not called correctly" mean?  are you getting some sort of error message? or getting some unexpected result?

Comment: Please see the details that I added in the ticket